# How to find the normal form under congruence of the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, matrix-congruences

Consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
                                     -1&1&-1\\
                                     -1&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$.
Suppose we want to find the normal form under congruence of matrices.Now after carrying out the first operation,the pivot positions are not in correct positions,so I am stuck here.Should I use row or column interchange for that.Please try to find normal form under congruence and show me the steps and help me to find my mistake.

Comment: What kind of normal form are you looking for? The matrix is orthogonally similar to $\operatorname{diag}(-1,2,2)$ over $\mathbb R$ and also congruent to $\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1)$.

Comment: @user1551 please note that I have written normal form under congruence.

Comment: Yes, and that was why I asked you which normal form you were looking for. Note that orthogonal similarity is a special case of congruence.

Comment: @user1551 normal form under congruence mean a diagonal matrix with diagonals having $1,-1,0$ sequentially.